# What exactly does "dps per LSB" mean?

Tags: c++, types, embedded, 32bit-64bit, can-bus

I just have bought a smart actuator with can bus protocol. And there is one command that use to control motor speed.
And it say

> "Speed Control is int32_t, which corresponds to the actual speed of
> 0.01dps/LSB"

What does 0.01 dps/LSB??
From my opinion int_32 is vary from(−2,147,483,648, +2,147,483,647) does it mean I can control motor from(−21,474,836 dps, +21,474,836 dps) which convert to RPM is (3579139 rpm , 3579139 rpm). Does it ever make sense???

Please help me understand.
Thank you.

Comment: I would read that as Speed Control being a value of hundredths of dps, so the range would be -21,474,836.48 to +21,474,836.47 dps.

Comment: It just means that the granularity in which you can control your motor is 0.01 dps. I.e. there is not possibility to make the motor faster by 0.005 dps. It does make any statements about min/max RPM.

Answer (score 0):

"dps per LSB" means "degrees per second per least significant bit".  That statement is specifying the resolution of the the Speed Control value.  The least significant bit represents 0.01 degrees per second.

Yes, because the Speed Control value is a 32-bit signed integer then the max/min could theoretically be +/- 3,579,139.4 RPM.  But you're extrapolating a min/max specification from the resolution specification.  There may be another min/max specification in the data sheet that you're overlooking.

If you're thinking that the min/max is too great and wondering why the value is 32-bits, then consider that if the value was 16-bit with the same resolution then the min/max would be only +/- 54.6 RPM, which is probably too small.  So the designers may have chosen 32-bits, which is more than enough, because 16-bits is not enough.